# How to easy create an office suit?

Tags: modeling

I'm looking for a way to create a classic office suit like in this picture:

[image]

Is there a fast way to make it? Maybe I should use a cloth simulation for it or shrinkwrap+subdiv modifiers?
I just haven't created a clothes so I don't know a good way to make it.

Comment: It's a philosophical question. What's easy? If you divide the job into small enough steps, none of them are hard at all. It could get time consuming... What's time consuming? How much time is too much to spend on this? Not sure if this question can be answered. Maybe you could tell us what you have tried as far and what you are struggling with?

Comment: There are many sites with low cost or free meshes that can be imported into your file.  [turbosquid](https://www.turbosquid.com/), [cgtrader](https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models) are two of my favorites where I've been lucky to find these.   DAZ studio (free) can also install some free characters and outfits that can then be exported/imported into blender.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys thank you for your attention. I've tried to create cylinder without caps, apply shrinkwrap and subdiv modifiers and try to adjust it to character, so it should be the fastest way to achieve my goal (as I thought). But the result is not so good.

Comment: Hello, yes you can create the basic shape and shrinkwrap onto the body

Comment: @james_t thank you for advice but I can't use that because of 2 reasons: I can't pay for this because of sanctions and I can't download models from here because sites doesn't work with my country (at least, cgtrader).